# When should recruiters call candidates instead of emailling?

Tags: recruitment, email, phone

Customarily, phone calls are used when the callers need to have the responses as soon as possible, or when they don't receive replies by other channels for whatever reasons. Receiving an important call at an inconvenient situation might create a bad impression on the receiver. However, for a recruiter who wants to offer a candidate a job position, when do they decide to call instead of emailing?

I think it's best for them to stick to email. Emails give both parties time to think and write, while phone calls usually end up with "thanks for the info, let me think about that", then emails will be used afterwards. An answer of [Do recruiters call twice to candidates?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/62888/26826) said that "recruiters who are truly interested in getting a response will [...] likely e-mail you rather than call", but it doesn't give any explanation. The only positive side of using phone calls I can think of is to making a pressure on the receivers, but I don't think they really want to do that.

So when should recruiters use phone call instead of email?

Comment: You're overthinking this (or asking the wrong question) - any given person would prefer one or the other (or both) and may not have a strict rule about which one to use in any given scenario. Phone calls are more personal, faster (especially with a lot of back and forth) and less likely to lead to misunderstandings. If you **are** a recruiter and you're wondering which approach to take, it would be better to phrase the question as such, because the question seems too broad / opinion-based at the moment.

Comment: Because some people prefer the phone over email. And for some aspects of recruitment it's useful to have a direct line of communication. But what are you actually asking? You're not asking whether they *should* so this seems to be mainly a question borne from idle curiosity and not one that can really have a practical answer.

Comment: @Lilienthal initially, my question is "when should". Since I'm not a recruiter, I think "when would" would be softer. But will changing to "should" makes the question not opinion-based anymore?

Comment: @Ooker Well, not really, because you're not a recruiter who's wondering if there's a best practice. That could perhaps be on-topic but it doesn't seem to be why you posted this question. If you have a look at the [help] you'll see the types of questions that we usually cover here. The issue with your question is that there's no real "answer" because there's no general but answerable question.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere as in my understanding, in a professional context when both two parties interacted with each other for the first time, emailing is an expected channel. Is that correct?

Comment: @Lilienthal why is that so important? Why shouldn't I ask what the boss think if I'm just an employee? Isn't the most important thing in every negotiation is putting yourself on their shoes? And how can I do that, if not asking this kind of questions?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm not sure. Maybe from my experience with how this works. I think the unclear-ness of my question stems from here. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think it is perfectly valid question to ask, if one wants to understand how a recruiting process usually works. Question could be improved if the OP would remove his personal preference for writing, though.

Comment: @Ooker I suggest checking out the [help] because that basically covers why it's important to ask a "good" question. Sure it might be useful to know what your boss thinks but how can a bunch of strangers on the internet possibly figure that out?

Comment: @Daniel which bit should be improved?

Comment: @Lilienthal I know how it's important to ask a good question, in fact, I'm trying to ask a clear, interesting one here. No one knows what my boss thinks, but their conclusions should base on rationale, depends on the context that the OP provides. The strangers on the internet will help me see the rationale that I cannot see.

Comment: @Ooker That's fair. Since you're interested in reworking this I suggest asking for feedback on [chat] and [meta]. People there can help you figure out what direction to take this in and how to word it so it's on-topic and clearly scoped.

Comment: @Lilienthal [Done](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4725/26826). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Phone Interview has a number of advantages too:

1. You get a rapid response, so if it is urgent to fill a position you can have them sitting in your office much faster.
2. You save a lot of time writing back and forth, only to find out in a face-to-face that the prospect can´t form a single sentence etc. - something that 5 minutes on the phone could tell you.
3. It gives you a first Impression of the type of personalty you are dealing with.
4. It can save both parties time and maybe travel-expenses for face-to-face interviews.

> So when would recruiters use phone call instead of email?

When they have a candidate that looks promising on paper, but they want minimize wasted resources for In-person interviews. 
This can be:

- They have 7 matches but only want to invite 3 to a face-to-face.
- They do this a standard to everyone who fits the profile. (*We do this*)
- They are undecided about you and want do find out more.
- They just want you to start working there *yesterday* and dont´t want to waste any time waiting for your reply.